# How to run async function as a thread in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a counting functions that sends a number every second to a text channel (it's in a while-true loop), while this is happening I want the bot to do other things as well such as answering commands in a different channel but it is stuck in that while-true loop.

I've tried using a call-back function but that didn't let me send any messages..

This is my full code:

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    text_channel = bot.get_channel(xxxxxxxxxxx)
    await count_in_server(text_channel)

@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send('pong')

@bot.event
async def count_in_server(chat):
    count = 0
    while True:
        await chat.send(count)
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        count += 1
```

My question more specfic is how do you run `count_in_server()` as a thread? (please provide code example)

EDIT:
Thanks to AKX I changed `asyncio.sleep(1)` to `await asyncio.sleep(1)` and now between each second it lets the other script run, but I'm looking for another way to do this.

Comment: You'll need to `await asyncio.sleep(1)`...

Comment: right but but I'm looking for a different what if I'm not using sleep?

Comment: What sort of "another way" do you need? You shouldn't be mixing async tasks with threads.

Comment: Why do you want to run it in a separate thread? None of the code inside is blocking, if you don't want to be that long inside the function you can create a task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
await count_in_server(text_channel)
```

replace the line above with:

```
asyncio.create_task(count_in_server(text_channel))
```

And you should be ok.
Tasks are scheduled to run in parallel. "awaited" coroutines block the code where the "await" keyword is until the target resolves.